# what would QList::first() returns if the list is empty?

Tags: c++, qt, stl, qlist

Here is the documentation of this function,

```
T & QList::first ()
```

> Returns a reference to the first item in the list. The list must not
>   be empty. If the list can be empty, call `isEmpty()` before calling this
>   function.

I am trying to figure out what would `QList::first()` return if the list was empty?

Comment: have you tried to implement that by yourself first?

Comment: If the docs don't say an exception is raised, then the safest bet is that it is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: If it says DON'T USE ON EMPTY LIST then don't do it. You will probably get a crash or even worse - memory corruption (or any other undefined behavior).

Comment: I would assume it throws an exception, but haven't ever tried it. Just do as they say and call isEmpty() first.

Answer (score 4):

A quick scan of the source ( reference: [`qtproject/qt`](https://github.com/qtproject/qt/blob/4.8/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h) ) shows that the call is protected by `QT_ASSERT(!isEmpty())` (for both overrides, `const` and non).

Without dredging through the source, I'm guessing that `QT_ASSERT` will call `terminate` or similar if built in debug, and will possibly be compiled out in release. Otherwise, the call to `QList::first` ultimately dereferences a pointer within the proxy-type `QListData::Data`, which would be undefined behaviour in your case.

In summary: don't do it

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at the corresponding `qlist.h` header. The implementation of `QList::first()` is as simple as

```
inline T& first() { Q_ASSERT(!isEmpty()); return *begin(); }
```

On an empty list the assertion will `abort()` your program.

Comment: From the QT documentation - "This means QList member functions CAN FAIL. If you define QT_NO_DEBUG when you compile, failures will not be detected. If you don't define QT_NO_DEBUG, failures will be detected using Q_ASSERT() or Q_ASSERT_X() with an appropriate message".

Answer (score 0):

> what would `QList::first()` return if the list was empty

It won't ever return. Seriously.

OTOH, I'm really puzzled by questions such as yours. If you can't try it out, perhaps you should set up your environment to make such experiments easy before you delve any deeper.